# Filter function usage Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter

I am trying to perform a simple simulation in Matlab.
I have a random signal x and a filter transfer function. What is the proper usage of the filter function?

```
x = rand(100,1);
syms z;
Pnum = (1-0.1*z^-1); 
Pdenum = (1-0.9*z^-1);

y = filter(Pnum, Pdenum, x);
```

This throws the error

> "Undefined function 'filter' for input arguments of type 'sym'."

I understand that it's complaining about the z variable. How should I go about solving it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter command is not built to take symbolic data types. It takes the raw filter coefficients as input. What it looks like you are trying to define is a difference equation where the b coefficients are .  .

```
b = [1 0.1];
```

and the a coefficients are

```
a = [1 0.9];
```

you can then filter the signal as follows

```
y = filter(b,a,x)
```

The freqz command reveals that this is a strange high pass filter with some gain . .

```
freqz(b,a)
```

[image]

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

If you reverse the coefficients so

```
b = [1 0.9];
a = [1 0.1];
```

...you end up with a low pass filter with some gain

```
freqz(b,a)
```

[image]

Comment: Those are just my first steps on a dsp/matlab ground and a step forward in solving my assignment:) Thanks very much for clarification.

Comment: Happy to push you in the right direction. Best of luck with the assignment